# Extract nanopore read ID & start times from fastq file

Tags: fastq, nanopore, awk

I have a fastq file from minION (albacore) that contains information on the read ID and the start time of the read. I want to extract these two bits of information into a single csv file.

I've been trying to figure out a grep/awk/sed solution, but without success.

E.g.

```
@93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720 runid=17838b1d08f30a031bf60afabb146a8b0fba7486 read=12217 ch=492 start_time=2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
CTATTGTCCCCTGCCGCTGCCCCTCCTGCTACGCCCCACTGCCTCACCAGCCGTTACGGTCGCCCCCCATCGCATGCCTTTACACACACACTTCTTTACACATGCTATCTTCCC
+
""*)&$-.,-(#"&'$%''+16#"$##&)%%/"+*(*(&#"&'%1"+)#)""%$$#&&'1%"'8>MJ<#'&%'.2'.$(&#'()'&&%'$('%"%%%..$#"&"#+&,*$%"#"
@ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c runid=17838b1d08f30a031bf60afabb146a8b0fba7486 read=8432 ch=200 start_time=2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
CGATGGCCGTATGCTTTTGTTATGAAGCGAAAAGCTGCTCGCTTCTCTAGATAATAATGATGTGGCGAAAACGCTATGCGATTCGTTGACATACATGATGGCGGATTTATCTACCACTTTGTGGCATGCTTTTCTCGCCAGATAATGGAATGTTTCTCTGGCGGTAATGGATAGTATCAAATCTCACTAGCCCATTCTATAAGCGCATCCGCATGCACTAGTTCTTGATTCGATCGTCCTCTAGCATGTTCGAAGAAGATAGCATTCACTATCATCATCGCCTCAGGTAAGTTTATTCGGTTGGGGCGTGTGAAGGCAAACACCTTGTTGTCCAGTAAGTTTTCAGTTACTATAACTTAAAGTCGCACATGAATCTAGTCTCCTATTCCCCACCCATGATCCCACTCACACATTTCTACAGAGATGTGGTTAGAAATTTTCATATTAGGTCAGCTTTGACTCAATAAGACATAATTCTTCACTGAATGACTTTTTAAGAACCACCAGGACCAGAGAGAACCAAGAGAGTGGTACCTCTTAAAACACAATAAAGTGATTCAGCCTTAGCCATTGGATTCTGGAGGACCTTGAACCATGTGGGAAGCAGCTCAGGGTGGCCATGTACTATACTGGCGGGTAAGCTTCTGGAGTGCTAGGTTCTTTTTGTCTTTTCTTAAGCATTGCCGCCAGTTGATTGGGTTTTGAACATAAAATAATGCGCCACCAGCAATTCCAGATTTGTTCCTACGGGATAGATTTGTTCAGTTCTAGCATTATGCTTCACTAACCAGATGCGGGCCCTAAGTCCTTCACTTGGAATATTGGATTGGATCATGAGAATATTCTGTCTGAAGCTCGTCATTAATTTTGTTACAAAATAGAGCTTTTTGACTGGAAGTACCACCATACGTGTTCTCAAACTTCAGCATTTTTAGAACTTCCCACGGCATCTTGACCCTTTTCACAGCATGGATAGTCAGGCAGCAGTGAACTTTGTGACTCTTTAATGCCTTCACTTTTCTCTCAGTTTCCCCGCCTTGCGTTATCTTTACTCGTCTTGGGACTTTTATCCCAATGCCAGCCTTCTACCCTGAGACCTCAGTGGGTCATCATCCCAGCCCGGGACATCTCATCCCATCATTTATGGGCTGTTGTGTTTTTTTCAAAACCTAGCCCTCTCAGGAGGAGGAGGAGTGGGAGTCAGTTCAGTGAGGAGGATTAGGATGATCTGAAATGTAAGCACATATAAGCGAAGCACTTATTTTGGGTTGGGTCCTCACGGTGGACATAAGATCGCCTTATGTGTTTAGTAAGCCATTCCTAGCTCTCAATGGCGTGATTACATAGAAGCGTGAGGGATCAGTCCTATGGAAGACTAGGAAGTAAATGAACAAAATATATTAACCATAGAAGTCTCATGGGTCGCTGTAGCCAAAAGATTAACACTTTTGACTACATTGTGGTTTTAGGCATTGAAACAAAAACTTTGAGTCTCCTAAACAAATGAATGGAAAATAGTAGCGAACTTCGATTCCTAACATTAAATCTAGAAATAGCAAGTTAGTTTAAAGACTTTATTTAGCTTTGCTTGCTATAATGAAAACCTTGCCTCCCGGTCGGGGCCATTGTGCCTGAAGCTAGCTTATTGTCTCCTCGAGCTCCCAGCTTCAGCAACTCCTTTTGAAGCGTTTGTCTCAGCTTGGATCTTCAGCAGCTCTTGGTGGCTCTTTTGAGCTAGCTCCTCTGAGATCTTGTATTTGGTAGGTCGCTTAGTCATAGTACTTTTCTTTTAACACCCTTCAGCTCTACGATTACATTTGGTTTTGTGGATATCATAATGATTGATGTGAAGATACATTGTACATGTG
+
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
```

Should produce

`93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720, 2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c, 2017-07-04T06:56:41Z`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
awk '{if(NR%4==1) print $1, $5}' file.fastq | sed -e "s/ start_time=/, /" -e "s/^@//"
```

The `awk` command gets the first of every 4 lines, printing the first and fifth "word". `sed` is then used to strip the initial `@` and replace `start_time=` with `,`. The output on your example file is:

```
93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720, 2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c, 2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

Comment: You could simplify your `awk` to `awk 'NR%4==1{print $1, $5}'`, if you like.

Answer (score 6):

Since the string `start_time` will only appear on the header line, or else you don't have a valid fastq file, you can simply do:

```
$ perl -ne '/^@(\S+).*start_time=(.*)/ && print "$1, $2\n"' file.fastq 
93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720,2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c,2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

Alternatively, since you mentioned `awk` and `sed`:

```
$ awk -v OFS=", " '/start_time/{print $1,$NF}' file.fastq | sed 's/start_time=//'
@93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720, 2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
@ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c, 2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

Or, doing the whole thing in `awk`:

```
$ awk 'sub(/start_time=/,""){print $1", "$NF}' file.fastq 
@93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720, 2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
@ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c, 2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

And if the `@` annoy you:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^@/,"") && sub(/ .*start_time=/,", ")' file.fastq 
93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720, 2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c, 2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

And in `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 's/^@\([^ ]*\).*start_time=\(.*\)/\1, \2/p' file.fastq 
93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720, 2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c, 2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

Or, if your sed supports it:

```
$ sed -En 's/^@(\S+).*start_time=(.*)/\1, \2/p' file.fastq 
93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720, 2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c, 2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

Finally, since `grep` can't do replacements, to use it you would have to do something like:

```
$ grep -oP '^@\K\S+|start_time=\K.*' file.fastq | paste - - 
93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720    2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c    2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

And to get the commas:

```
$ grep -oP '^@\K\S+|start_time=\K.*' file.fastq | paste - - | sed 's/\t/, /'
93a12f52-95e5-40c7-8c3e-70bf94ed0720, 2017-07-04T06:42:43Z
ff37e422-a25f-404c-8314-ef1733f9c30c, 2017-07-04T06:56:41Z
```

Answer (score 3):

Albacore produces a `sequencing_summary.txt` file (actually TSV, not CSV) in the same directory as the `workspace` folder that might have the data that you want in it. Here are the fields present in that file:

- filename
- **read_id**
- run_id
- channel
- **start_time**
- duration
- num_events
- template_start
- num_events_template
- template_duration
- num_called_template
- sequence_length_template
- mean_qscore_template
- strand_score_template
- complement_start
- num_events_complement
- complement_duration
- num_called_complement
- sequence_length_complement
- mean_qscore_complement
- strand_score_complement
- sequence_length_2d
- mean_qscore_2d

Comment: We'd thought the same. The issue is that the start_time that albacore calculates is actually the time since the start of a run. This is fine if you keep your minION switched on for a whole run. But if you reset it occasionally (which we do, because it really seems to increase yields) then the start_time column is a lot less useful.